# Error in installing the scikit-learn-extra

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
pip install scikit-learn-extra
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-learn-extra

pip install https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/scikit-learn-extra/archive/master.zip
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-learn-extra
Failed to build scikit-learn-extra
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-learn-extra which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

these were the error I get while installing the scikit-learn-extra. how should I solve the issue?

Comment: What platform/OS are you on? Can you use the `--verbose` option (possibly multiple times) to show some more details?

Comment: It appears your problem has been recognised ( https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/scikit-learn-extra/issues/59 ), but either the wheels are not yet available, or not available for your platform.

Comment: Also, from the [README file](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/scikit-learn-extra/blob/master/README.rst#user-installation): "Note that installing from PyPi requires a working C compiler (cf installation instructions)."

Comment: I'm currently using the windows 10 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Until there is an appropriate wheel (binary file) available for your OS, you either have to wait, or try to build it yourself. In the latter case, you'd need to have a C compiler, and probably corresponding libraries, installed.

You can see if there are any wheels available on PyPI, in the Downloads section: https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn-extra/#files . It doesn't appear there are any yet (work in progress); compare with https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/#files .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which python version you're using.
I faced the same issue while applying python 3.9 (iMacPro, OSX 11.2.1), and have managed to overcome it by switching for python 3.8 (3.8.7), plus upgrading pip manager (`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`).
Hope it will work for you as well